# C++ копирующий конструктор

Tags: c++, конструктор

у меня возникли некоторые сложности с пониманием материала. В книге, которую я сейчас прохожу по C++, написано, что: *неявный конструктор копирования осуществляет копирование по значению*, однако прочитав документацию https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor, там показаны шаблоны где явно видна T::T(const T&) передача по ссылке

Comment: да, передаётся ссылка, но копируется содержимое, тут нет противоречий, вы ведь можете использовать ссылку в `memcpy`

Comment: Всё, посидел и подумал ещё, сам сделал пример и разобрался как оно работает, спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Что за книга? Глава, номер страницы? Издание?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это другое)

В данном случае производится две передачи данных -- из внешней программы в конструктор (аргумент конструктора) и из конструктора в память объекта.

Первая из них -- по константной ссылке. Вторая по значению.